# Почему время от времени вылезает ошибка "подключение ограниченно или отсутствует"?

Tags: wifi, модемы

Интернет подключен, работает стабильно в течение некоторого времени (бывает даже весь день без перебоя), потом вылезает надпись:

> подключение ограниченно или отсутствует

Перезагрузка, отключение карты и повторное включение, выключение на долгое время, не помогает в большинстве случаев. Но когда я, выключая питание на процессоре (фильтр), включаю его снова, включаю компьютер - всё как новенькое работает! В квартире стоит 2 компьютера: один старенький (на нём никогда с интернетом проблем не было), и современный, с ним такая беда (локалка от материнки).

Comment: Интернет у вас через роутер (модем)?

Comment: да стоит модем 4 портовый с вайфаем, вот минут 20 назад была обратно проблема, работает работает и бах сетевой кабель не подключен и все..) спасло отключение фильтра на 20 минут!

Comment: Есть возможность поставить и попробовать дополнительную сетевую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте очищать кеш DNS, и полазьте в настройках сетевух (через Диспетчер устройств). А вообще, чтоб комп не выключать все время, можно в том же Диспетчере удалить сетевуху, затем "Поиск нового оборудования". Типа небольшой ресет настроек сетевухи. Должно помочь.

Comment: отключить сетевуху и заново ее задействовать не работает, пробовал  много раз... результата не дало! а как кеш DNS очищать?и какие настройки мне надо посмотреть?

Comment: `ipconfig /flushdns` очистка кэш

Comment: А настройка -- смотрите в свойствах сетевухи на вкладке Дополнительно. Для каждого драйвера каждой карты там могут быть различные настройки, так что точнее не могу, попробуйте сами...

Comment: кеш очистил вчера, проблема сегодня вновь повторилась, сетевой кабель не подключен...)

Comment: И вот что: я так понял, у Вас интернет от встроенной, @Dex верно заметил: попробуйте, по-возможности, поставить другую сетевуху. Кроме того, есть такая опция: Disable Task Offload, попробуйте изменить... Она скорее всего ничего не даст, но мало ли... Кроме того, попробуйте руками: возможно у Вас где-то перегрев, скажем, самой сетевухи, или моста, и срабатывает защита. Тогда поставьте доп. кулер. Более того, я уверен, смотря на временную характеристику, что дело именно в перегреве. То есть в самом железе, а не в софте и настройках. Заодно, проверьте правильное заземление компа.

Comment: сетевая встроенная, на материнки"проверьте правильное заземление компа" - это как?"Disable Task Offload"- нужно через реестр изменять?HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters создать dword-параметр "DisableTaskOffload" и присвоить ему значение 0."доп. кулер" - его куда воткнуть?я так понял лучший вариант просто купить новую сетевуху?

Comment: насчет проблемы с сетевухой я даже больше чем уверен, потому что когда это происходит,(лампочка на сетевухе не горит) я высоуваю провод и обратно а лампочка не загорается...! и на модеме тоже погасает, как будто провод не воткнут! замена провода не помогла...!

Comment: Заземление компа -- это многие детали могут перегреваться из-за отсутствия заземления, из-за чего на корпусе компа есть порядка 100 вольт. Да, через реестр. Кулер воткните туда, что именно греется (по возможности).Да, если не поможет замена кабеля и все остальное, то придется покупать. Только встроенную придется отключить.